# Activator.CreateInstance fails but Server.CreateObject works

Tags: .net, vb.net, vbscript

I have the following vbscript code that creates an instance of a server object without any errors:

```
Dim myObject: Set myObject = Server.CreateObject( "MyProject.Class" )
```

When I try the following .net equivalent in vb.net (.net 3.5),

```
Dim myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID( "MyProject.Class"))
```

i get an exception "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type"

Any ideas?

Comment: This link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hss5hw09(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Try putting the code on separate lines. Its a null arg exception, so more than likely Type.GetTypeFromProgID("foo") is returning a null value. It can't find the type, perhaps the prog id string you specified is invalid?

Comment: @James: Yes, Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyProject.Class") is returning a null value, but shouldn't Server.CreateObject("MyProject.Class") fail too? The prog ids are exactly the same.

Comment: @HansPassant: I am running it in a 32-bit Windows Server 2003 SP2 (IIS 6.0). Target CPU setting is set to x86

Comment: You are obfuscating details, never a good idea.  Clearly it cannot possibly be called "MyProject.Class", vb.net doesn't allow that.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility to see COM searching the registry.  Compare the traces you get from the working and non-working cases.

Comment: I will try SysInternals' ProcMon utility and let you know if it helped. I used "MyProject.Class" to avoid posting the actual project and class name.

Comment: @HansPassant: Restarting the web server (iisreset) seems to have fixed this issue. I still don't understand why the vbscript code worked and the .net one failed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem with CPApplet.CPAppletMgr.  VBScript is just fine and .NET blows chunks.  My type is not coming back null it just won't activate the object.  This was after I first tried using VS to generate the COM reference and it failed also.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: This might help maybe https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/cb3e91a8-2157-4de3-94aa-f48c129e06fd/cant-create-object-cpappletcpappletmgr-error-0x800a01ad?forum=configmgrgeneral. Also you might want to check what version of CPApplet you are using (x86 or x64)

Comment: I'm starting a new question. I have a simple VBS that works but fails if I call it from Process.Start.  Something about my EXE's process is blocking it from seeing the class.